# Generate separate SINGLE xml for multiple sql queries using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I am trying to generate xml from sql query. I need to combine the result of more than one sql query and generate a one single xml which will be enclosed in root attributes.

I have blow C# code

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            XmlReader reader;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc;
            DataTable rnos = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                string connString = "Connection";
                conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TopSection where r_no NOT like'C%' and s_seq='1'",conn);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(rnos);

                DataRow dr;

                string cmd1= @"SELECT
    (SELECT * FROM TopSection where r_no = @rno and s_seq=1  FOR XML PATH('Top'), TYPE) AS 'Tops',
    (SELECT * FROM office where r_no = @rno and s_seq=1 FOR XML PATH('Office'), TYPE) AS 'Offices',
    (SELECT * FROM complete where r_no= @rno and s_seq=1 FOR XML PATH('Complete'), TYPE) AS 'Completes',"+"FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root') ,ELEMENTS XSINIL";

     for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                { 
                     dr = rnos.Rows[i];
                    string no= dr["r_no"].ToString();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd1, conn);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@rno", SqlDbType.Char, 20).Value = no;
                     reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
                    xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        xmlDoc.Load(reader);
                    }
                     xmlDoc.Save("C:TopSection-" + i + ".xml");
                     }


            }
            catch(SqlException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to generate separate xml if I use only one query but I want to pull records from different sql tables using the same r_no and combine them together and save it as a xml. I am getting and error in correct syntax at FOR. I am looking out out as xml like this

```
<root>
    <tops>
    <top>----</top>
        <top>----</top>
    </tops>
    <offices>
    <office>----</office>
    <office>----</office>
    </offices>
    <completes>
    <complete>---</complete>
    <complete>---</complete>
        </completes>
   </root>
```

Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have a stray comma after `'Completes'`. You'd immediately see this if you printed the string, or copied it in SSMS.

Comment: Adding to @JeroenMostert comment, give a single blank space before `FOR XML PATH('')`

Comment: It worked thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something simple :

```
       const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(INPUT_FILENAME );

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, settings);

            writer.WriteStartElement("root");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                writer.WriteRaw(reader.ReadOuterXml());
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();


        }
```